# CloudFlare Cache Issue

Tags: nginx, caching, amazon-ec2, cloudflare, amazon-lightsail

I was using Amazon LightSail server with lot of media files like mp3 and images, I was using CloudFlare as CDN to cache data and it cached lot of data with no problem. Later for some reasons I have to transfer my website data from LightSail to Amazon EC2 and thought by changing IP with CloudFlare DNS will keep my past cache with cloudflare because urls of all files are same. I checked different urls and found cache status was HIT, later found cache HIT status is not consistent. I set nginx server header origin like that now

```
 add_header Cache-Control "public,max-age=315360000,immutable";
```

Check the Image below

[image]

But still it looks cache is rebuilding and I am being charged heavily for data transfer from Amazon. Any suggestion what I did wrong and what should be done at this stage?

Comment: Unless you are paying for the highest level Cloudflare account, Cloudflare is going to delete pages of your site from their cache if isn't accessed extremely often. Unless you are paying for the tiered-cache option as well, then Cloudflare is going to keep separate versions of your site cached in each Cloudflare datacenter, so even if it is cached in one data center another one will still have a cache MISS. And they have over 200 data centers https://www.cloudflare.com/network/

Comment: This toll might help you find what the issue is https://cf-cache-status.com/